# Erlang: extended gen_server

Tags: erlang, gen-server

I want to extend `gen_server` (create a `gen_server_extra`) with some additional functionality. The requirements are:

1. The `gen_server_extra` processes should behave like a regular `gen_server`'s. E.g, they should accept calls via `gen_server:call`, integrate with SASL, fit OTC supervision tree, etc.
2. `gen_server_extra` processes should have an additional functionality, provided by `gen_server_extra`. That basically means some of the messages will be handled by `gen_server_extra` code, without passing them to the callback module. The rest of the messages are passed to callback module as is.
3. `gen_server_extra` functionality requires its own state which should be hidden from the callback module.

What is the simplest approach to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best, most modular approach would be to implement a new behavior in a module (e.g. `gen_ext_server`) and wrap the `gen_server` behavior from there.

First, make sure your behavior is identical to `gen_server`:

```
-module(gen_ext_server).
-behavior(gen_server).

% Exports...

behaviour_info(Type) -> gen_server:behaviour_info(Type).
```

Implement all callbacks needed for `gen_server`, keep the name of the callback module that implements your behavior in your state:

```
init([Mod|ExtraArgs]) ->
    % ...
    ModState = Mod:init(ExtraArgs),
    #state{mod = Mod, mod_state = ModState, internal = [...]}
```

Then, in each `gen_server` callback, implement your behavior and then call the callback module if needed:

```
handle_call(internal, _From, State) ->
    % Do internal stuff...
    {reply, ok, State};
handle_call(Normal, From, State = #state{mod = Mod, mod_state = ModState}) ->
    case Mod:handle_call(Normal, From, ModState) of
        {reply, Reply, NewState} ->
            {reply, Reply, #state{mod_state = NewState};
        ... ->
            ...
    end.
```

Implement similar functionality for `handle_cast/2`, `handle_info/2`, `terminate/1` etc.

Comment: Yeah, after some thinking I came to the similar design. The only problem is lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: The behaviors in OTP aren't really extendible, which is understandable because it would have impact on performance and simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

well, i would not call it customization, but rather a new behavior. You need to define your own behavior. **[A tutorial which will take you through this](http://www.trapexit.org/Defining_Your_Own_Behaviour)** is found at trapexit.org.
However, the requirements are not very proper.

The main essence of giving the call back functions access to the server state is to write normal sequential code manipulating the state of your application when and where you want without interrupting the concurrency details.
Otherwise if that is the way to go, implement your own behavior.